# Run the next line in javascript after the previous function from 3rd library is done (not jquery)

Tags: javascript

In our website, there is a call tracking script which directly runs after the user select their countries in the contact page.

And the process is as follows:
1.Customers click into the list and select the country that they are in, and in this stage we start to track once they click into the element

2.The script from 3rd part runs, changes the telephone number in the website by replace the previous class with a new one with new number

3.Then we want to get the new number in the next line.

The planned script looked like this:

```
   orgCallNo = document.querySelector(".oldTel").innerHTML;
    var x = setInterval(function (){ 
      telephone.change();
      var newCallNo = document.querySelector(".tel").innerHTML;
      if (newCallNo !== orgCallNo) {
        console.log(newCallNo);
        clearInterval(x);
        }
      }, 20);
```

The problem is, when I called the external script i.e telephone change script, it takes a while and the next line takes the old input and continue the process, before the telephone script has been completed.

To solve it, I have already tried the setTimeOut function to a kind of pause the next step:

```
orgCallNo = document.querySelector(".oldTel").innerHTML;
var x = setInterval(function (){ 
  telephone.change();
  var newCallNo = setTimeout(function(){return 
                  document.querySelector(".tel").innerHTML;}, 300);
  if (newCallNo !== orgCallNo) {
    console.log(newCallNo);
    clearInterval(x);
    }
  }, 20);
```

However it returns undefined. At the same time, I want to try to use the call back function, but first, most of the solutions are in jQuery, which I cannot use in this time. And the second point is, the script uses the library from 3rd party and did not directly return some input in the script, therefore I am not sure when to set the call back function.

In this case, how can I make sure that the next line runs after the script from 3rd party completed? 
Thanks for you guys help =)

Comment: 2 questions: 1. can you please provide the link to this library and say, which method do you call in your real project? 2. Does this method from library accept any arguments and is this method asynchronous? Does it return something?

Comment: *"...it takes a while and the next line takes the old input and continue the process, before the telephone script has been completed."* `setInterval` will do that, is there a reason why you need to use it? This is too much work without HTML please post relevant HTML as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readyState` for loading this external library, like this you detect when this 3rd library is loaded (better than setTimeout)

Sample code :

```
function loadScript( url, callback ) {
  var script = document.createElement( "script" )
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  if(script.readyState) {  //IE
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ( script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete" ) {
        script.onreadystatechange = null;
        callback();
      }
    };
  } else {  //Others
    script.onload = function() {
      callback();
    };
  }

  script.src = url;
  document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( script );
}


// call the function...
loadScript(pathtoscript, function() {
  console.log('script ready! i can now execute my code...'); 
});
```